# Vertical alignment of tikzpicture in cell of a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

There is a whitespace in the bottom of cells in column "Results", but no whitespace in the top of cells in that column. Also cells in column "Criteria" are not vertically aligned.

Any ideas how to fix this?

### Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
    trafficlight:red/.style = {%
        matrix of nodes,
        ampersand replacement=\&,
        nodes in empty cells,
        rounded corners,
        draw = blue!70,
        fill = blue!30,
        nodes = {circle, minimum size=3mm, anchor=center, draw=black},
        column 1/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
        column sep=3mm,
    },
    trafficlight:green/.style = {%
    matrix of nodes,
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes in empty cells,
    rounded corners,
    draw = blue!70,
    fill = blue!30,
    nodes = {circle, minimum size=3mm, anchor=center, draw=black},
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    column sep=3mm,
    },
    trafficlight:yellow/.style = {%
    matrix of nodes,
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes in empty cells,
    rounded corners,
    draw = blue!70,
    fill = blue!30,
    nodes = {circle, minimum size=3mm, anchor=center, draw=black},
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column sep=3mm,
    }
}

%%% Работа с таблицами
\usepackage{tabularx} % Дополнительная работа с таблицами
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | c | Y | }
        \hline
        Results & Criteria \\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[trafficlight:red]{\& \& \\};
        \end{tikzpicture} & Test \\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[trafficlight:yellow]{\& \& \\};
        \end{tikzpicture} & Test \\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[trafficlight:green]{\& \& \\};
        \end{tikzpicture} & Test \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Do you want to remove the space entirely? Then add `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]` to your `{tikzpicture}` environments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @AlanMunn No, I want to make this space symmetric from top and bottom for all cells (inside cell) in both "Results" and "Criteria" columns. Your suggestion remove space in Results column but make this space shifted to top in Criteria column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following suggestion gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, 
                matrix}
\newcommand\Semafor[3]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.5mm]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes = {circle, draw, fill=#1,
                      minimum size = 4mm, inner sep=0mm, anchor=center},
             column sep = 1.5mm,
             ampersand replacement=\&
             ]
{
|[#1]| \&  |[#2]|    \&  |[#3]|  \\
};
\node[draw, rounded corners, inner sep=1mm, fit=(m)] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c] X[m, cmd={\RaggedRight}]},
                 row{1}  = {cmd={\Centering}},
                 row{2-Z}= {rowsep = 5pt}
                 }
Results                         &   Criteria    \\
\Semafor{red}{gray}{gray}       &   \lipsum[66] \\
\Semafor{gray}{yellow}{gray}    &   Test        \\
\Semafor{gray}{gray}{green}     &   Test        \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- In comparison with your code is definition of semaphore (named `\semafor`) much shorter and simpler.
- Definition of `\semafore` contain also option `baseline, which vertical shift image baseline so, that image is vertically centered with vertical center of adjacent cells.
- For table is used `tabularray` package, which enable by default insert the same vertical space below and above cells contents.
- For align text in the second column is used `\RaggedRigh` instruction. If you prefer horizontally centered text, replace `cmd={\Raggedright}` with `c` and than remove code line `row{1}  = {cmd={\Centering}},` too.

[image]