Tabular environment
How can I make the red row to be located in the middle of the cell?

Here is my code
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Hình ảnh mô tả} & \textbf{Vị trí tương đối của 2 đường tròn} \\
\hline
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Circle [id:dp32140079939613586] 
\draw   (56,130) .. controls (56,104.04) and (77.04,83) .. (103,83) .. controls (128.96,83) and (150,104.04) .. (150,130) .. controls (150,155.96) and (128.96,177) .. (103,177) .. controls (77.04,177) and (56,155.96) .. (56,130) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp08233777289142008] 
\draw   (208,131) .. controls (208,117.19) and (219.19,106) .. (233,106) .. controls (246.81,106) and (258,117.19) .. (258,131) .. controls (258,144.81) and (246.81,156) .. (233,156) .. controls (219.19,156) and (208,144.81) .. (208,131) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7590135646039362] 
\draw    (104,130) -- (234,130) ;
\draw [shift={(234,130)}, rotate = 0] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]      (0, 0) circle [x radius= 2.34, y radius= 2.34]   ;
\draw [shift={(104,130)}, rotate = 0] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]      (0, 0) circle [x radius= 2.34, y radius= 2.34]   ;

% Text Node
\draw (93,132) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {O};
% Text Node
\draw (235,134) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {O'};
% Text Node
\draw (154,111) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {A};
% Text Node
\draw (195,111) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {B};


\end{tikzpicture}
 & OO'>R+R'$\Leftrightarrow$ (O) và (O') ngoài nhau.\\
\hline
Dòng 2, Cột 1 & Dòng 2, Cột 2 \\
\hline
Dòng 3, Cột 1 & Dòng 3, Cột 2 \\
\hline
Dòng 4, Cột 1 & Dòng 4, Cột 2 \\
\hline
Dòng 5, Cột 1 & Dòng 5, Cột 2 \\
\hline
Dòng 6, Cột 1 & Dòng 6, Cột 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


Welcome to TeX. SE! Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with \documentclass{...} and ending with\end{document}, which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is.

See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702950/ can help you.

You could also browse existing questions and answers as this question pops up quite often ...

You want to set the baseline of the picture and also to simplify the input.
I suggest not to use vertical rules that don't help readability (actually, they hinder it). The letters, in my opinion, should be in math mode.
Why specifying the circles with control points?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Hình ảnh mô tả} & \textbf{Vị trí tương đối của 2 đường tròn} \\
\midrule
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=0.75pt,
  y=0.75pt,
  yscale=-1,
  xscale=1,
  line width=0.75pt,
  baseline=(current bounding box.west),
]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Circle [id:dp32140079939613586] 
\draw (56,130) .. controls (56,104.04) and (77.04,83) .. 
      (103,83) .. controls (128.96,83) and (150,104.04) .. 
      (150,130) .. controls (150,155.96) and (128.96,177) .. 
      (103,177) .. controls (77.04,177) and (56,155.96) .. (56,130) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp08233777289142008] 
\draw (208,131) .. controls (208,117.19) and (219.19,106) .. 
      (233,106) .. controls (246.81,106) and (258,117.19) ..
      (258,131) .. controls (258,144.81) and (246.81,156) ..
      (233,156) .. controls (219.19,156) and (208,144.81) ..
      (208,131) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7590135646039362] 
\draw (104,130) -- (234,130) ;
\draw [
  shift={(234,130)},
  rotate = 0,
  color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 },
  fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }
] (0, 0) circle [x radius= 2.34, y radius= 2.34] ;
\draw [
  shift={(104,130)},
  rotate = 0,
  color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 },
  fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 },
] (0, 0) circle [x radius= 2.34, y radius= 2.34] ;

% Text Node
\draw (93,132) node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0.75pt,align=left] {$O$};
% Text Node
\draw (235,134) node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0.75pt,align=left] {$O'$};
% Text Node
\draw (154,111) node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0.75pt,align=left] {$A$};
% Text Node
\draw (195,111) node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0.75pt,align=left] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 & $OO'>R+R' \Leftrightarrow (O)$ và $(O')$ ngoài nhau.\\
\midrule
Dòng 2, Cột 1 & Dòng 2, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 3, Cột 1 & Dòng 3, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 4, Cột 1 & Dòng 4, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 5, Cột 1 & Dòng 5, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 6, Cột 1 & Dòng 6, Cột 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Your main problem is already solved by @egreg answer (by add [baseline=(current bounding box.west) to tikzpicture options), so here are some suggestion how you can simpler draw your image and make your table a bit nicer (at least to my opinion) by use of the tblr of tabularray which enables simple adding of vertical space around rows contents:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
                booktabs,
                varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,
                positioning}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {cc},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep  = 5pt
             }
Hình ảnh mô tả  & Vị trí tương đối của 2 đường tròn \\

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west),
node distance = 32mm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=#1},
   dot/.style = {C=3pt, fill, inner sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small}
                        ]
\node (n1)  [dot, label=below:$O$] {};
\node (n2)  [C=22mm, name path=A] {};
%
\node (n3)  [dot, label=below:$O'$,
             right=of n1] {};
\node (n4)  [C=13mm, name path=B] at (n3)    {};
%
\draw[name path=C] (n1) -- (n3);
%
\fill [name intersections={of=A and C, by={[label=above right:A]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=B and C, by={[label=above  left:B]}}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
                &   $OO'>R+R' \Leftrightarrow (O)$ và $(O')$ ngoài nhau. \\
Dòng 2, Cột 1   & Dòng 2, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 3, Cột 1   & Dòng 3, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 4, Cột 1   & Dòng 4, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 5, Cột 1   & Dòng 5, Cột 2 \\
Dòng 6, Cột 1   & Dòng 6, Cột 2 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}    


